# masstransit semver error on rake build

Tags: c#, build, rake, masstransit

I keep getting the following error when trying to build the masstransit source from github:

```
Building for .NET 3.5
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- semver

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

with the --trace switch I get:

```
Building for .NET 3.5
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- semver
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Users/****/Dev/Scratch/MassTransit/build_support/versioning.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Users/****/Dev/Scratch/MassTransit/rakefile.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Is this supposed to be able to build out of the box or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOH!!

```
gem install albacore
gem install semver2
```

https://github.com/phatboyg/MassTransit

:)

Comment: fixed - nowadays Chris has added a fake SolutionVersion.cs file as well, so this shouldn't be needed anymore if you aren't looking to create nugets